# Spring Rest Template Url contains complex query

Tags: java, spring, rest, url-encoding, resttemplate

I want to call a web service which takes in url a query parametre.
This is the query :

```
{PK} IN({{Select {o.name}  from {Student! as o} where {o.name} IN ({{Select {s.pk} 
 from {School as s} where {s.code}="school"}})}})
```

I encode the query using [this](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm)

And i put the encoded query in web service url : http://host?query=query_above_encoded.

So when a do this (call the web service using `resttemplate`):

```
ResponseEntity<Model> response = restTemplate.exchange(
                    url, HttpMethod.GET, request, Model.class);
```

I get this exception :

> org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 Erreur Interne de Servlet

But when I call the same url using a rest client app (as Postman) a get the response.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use URI JAVA object after encoding the url:

```
ResponseEntity<Model> response = restTemplate.exchange(
                    new URI(encodedUrl), HttpMethod.GET, request, Model.class);
```

Hope this help someone else.